# Symfony2 Twig loading templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I am having some trouble telling twig which template to load.

I have a file located in MyBundle/Resources/Views/Admin/Project/list.html.twig

When I declare: return '`MyBundle:Admin:Project:list.html.twig`' I get the following error:

```
Unable to find template
```

If I move the file out of the Project directory i.e. `MyBundle/Admin/list.html.twig` and declare: `return 'MyBundle:Admin:list.html.twig`' the template is rendered. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Levon, Ill try to keep this in mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyBundle:Admin:Project/list.html.twig
```